# Post a form without uploading files for validation

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form with files. I would like to perform a **server-side** validation and only then upload the files (since each file makes the request larger).

Is there slick way to do that doesn't include serializing the form's data and running an ajax?

I'm **not** looking for something like this:

```
var formData = $('#form').serializeArray();
$.post(url, formData, function(res){
    if(res.isValid)
       $('#form').submit();
});
```

Comment: There is: you can find plenty of validation plugins.

Comment: validate where? client side? server side?

Comment: If you can implement the validation in JavaScript (without AJAX), then yes. Otherwise, you'll need AJAX.

Comment: I've edited - I'm looking for a way to post the data without uploading the files.

Comment: Maybe you should divide your form into two parts, first submit your generell data and after that you allow your user to fill in a second form with the file... well, it depends on your needs

Comment: Validate, set data in session, return form with file upload field.

Comment: @bukart - I thought about doing that, but I think it's less elegant.

Comment: @AmirPopovich mhh... than I don't see an "elegant" way to do it server sided, by submitting a form one http-request is made to the server, and you cannot repeat it by the server with some more parameters or so... there's a fault in your wanted behaviour.. sry :-(

Comment: ok... a "dirty elegant" way would be to route your request through a proxy. the proxy gets the full form and your server will be requested by the proxy... well, but also in the case your users will have to upload the file... Why you want to avoid the upload? So save bandwidth for your users?

Comment: @bukart - The proxy way is super ugly. And I want the user to upload the form faster. The form has lot's of inputs and files and it's most likely a user will have validation issues.

Comment: @AmirPopovich well, I added my final thoughts as an answer below

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (for **Client side validation**) , onclick of submit button

```
var file = $('#file_upload').prop("files")[0]; //file_upload is form's id
var name = file.name;
var size = file.size;
var type = file.type;

if (type != 'image/png' && type != 'image/jpeg' )throw {"msg": 'Invalid image type'}

if (size > 1024 * 1024 * 2 )throw {"msg": 'Invalid image size'}
```

And for AJAX **Server Side Validation** before upload, you need to send file object via Ajax( ***not recommended, might not work in few old browsers)

```
  try {

    var formObj = new FormData($('form')[1]); //File Object

    $.ajax({
      url: "YOUR URL", // do the SERVER SIDE VALIDATION here 
      data: formObj,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      dataType:'json',
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data){
        // Success code
      }
    }); 

  }catch (e) {
    console.log(e.msg);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`out.html` is entry point. `submitValidate` submits form in iframe (`in.html`). JavaScript snippet (`confirm.html`) in response from server passes database record to `validateClientSideAndUpload` which sets hidden field and submits form in parent window to server. Server moves file to appropriate location and creates association with record speficied by id. Posted as a proof of concept.

> **out.html**

```
<script>
function submitValidate() {
    document.getElementById('validate-frame')
        .contentDocument.querySelector('form').submit();
}
function validateClientSideAndUpload(id) {
    if(document.getElementById('file').value === '') {
        alert('Select file');
        return;
    }
    document.getElementById('record-id').value = id;
    var form = document.querySelector('form');
    if confirm('Upload file?') {
        form.submit();
    }
}
</script>

<iframe src="in.html" id="validate-frame"></iframe>
<form>
    <input type="file" id="file"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="record-id"/>
</form>
<button onclick="submitValidate()">Save</button>
```

> **in.html** (new/invalid)

```
<form action="confirm.html">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="data">
</form>
```

> **confirm.html** (success)

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    parent.validateClientSideAndUpload(/* server generated record id */);
}
</script>
```